# SQL - How to create a good query, if the field has a null value?

Tags: mysql

I have a record in database like this :

tablename : progreen

```
------------------------
id  name  proid  specid
------------------------
 1  A01     1      null
 2  A02     19     4
 3  A03     6      2
------------------------
```

Myquery :

if i do this `select * from progreen where proid = 1 and specid = null;`  the result is `null`, it should display the first row.

if i do this `select * from progreen where proid = 19 and specid = 4;` it's working well

How to create a good query, if the field has a null value ?

Whether to use *sql if statement in where clause* ?

Comment: Check for nulls as `is null`, not with `=`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * from progreen WHERE specid IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `=` operator for comparing `null` and need to use `is null`
Here are some exapmple

```
mysql> select null= null ;
+------------+
| null= null |
+------------+
|       NULL |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1 = null ;
+----------+
| 1 = null |
+----------+
|     NULL |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 1 is null ;
+-----------+
| 1 is null |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select null is null ;
+--------------+
| null is null |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the query will be

```
select * from progreen where proid = 1 and specid is null;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using IS NULL or column_name = ''

```
SELECT * FROM progreen WHERE proid = 1 AND specid = '';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM progreen WHERE proid = 1 AND specid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all of you who tried to answer of my question.
I tried to use this query for resolve my issue:

```
select * from progreen 
where proid = 19 --> this value you can insert 1 / 6
and IF(specid is null, 1=1, specid = 4) -->this value you can insert null / 2
```

it's work very well.
Thx again

Answer (score 0):

Adding some detailed info..

Simply put null is undefined,but there are operations which yield some different results

```
select 1+null--null
select 'A'+null--null

select 1+isnull(null,0)
select 'A'+isnull(null,'n')--null


---some info on nulls

create table #test1
(
id int,
name char(5)
)


create table #test2
(
id int
)

insert into #test2 
select 2
union all
select null



insert into #test1
select 1,'a'
union all
select null,'b'
union all
select 3,null

--getting data for all non  null fields
select 
* from #test1  where id is not null

select * from #test1 where id is null

---all aggregate functions exclude nulls
select sum(id),max(name)
from #test1

---but group by keeps nulls in seperate group
select 
sum(id),name
from #test1
group by name


---while comparing or joining against other fields --use is null,since we dont know it may be potentiallly null

select id  from #test1 t1 where   exists( select 1 from #test2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)--gives correct results

select id  from #test1 t1 where  not  exists( select 1 from #test2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)--gives correct results


select id  from #test1 t1 where  id in ( select id from #test2)--gives correct results

select id  from #test1 t1 where  id not in ( select id from #test2)--not gives correct results
```